# parser combinator in Scala output

Tags: scala, parsing

For this input in a file: `{right; left; straight}` I have this parser:

```
def conf: Parser[Any] = "{"  ~> feat <~ "}"
def feat: Parser[Any] = repsep(expr, ";") 
def expr = """[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])*""".r
```

which is giving to me this output: `List(right, left, straight)`

Now I need these elements, in this list, to iterate through them but I can't because when I am trying to use the for() loop it is saying that "value filter is not a member of com.xxx.ParseResult[Any]". How I can iterate and take the values from this parsed List??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `: Parser[Any]` type ascriptions make the result of your parsing `Any`, rather than the `List[String]` you need for the rest of your code. If you eliminate them, the compiler will infer the correct type of `Parser[List[String]]` on its own:

```
def conf = "{"  ~> feat <~ "}"
def feat = repsep(expr, ";") 
def expr = """[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])*""".r
```

The second issue is that you are trying to use the `ParseResult` directly. You need to invoke `.getOrElse` on it to either get the `List[String]` contained inside or provide an alternative if parsing failed:

```
val ls = parseResult.getOrElse(throw new Exception("parsing failed"))
```

Comment: Still it doesn't chose the problem. This is what I am trying to do:                `val rd = new FileReader(args(0))
val pval = parseAll(conf, rd)
    println(pval) //here I get the List(right, left, straight)`
  // But I waht to read the List values differently: one by one not as a List now.  When I try this: `for(nm <- pval) { ..}` I get the same message just now with `List[String]`.

Comment: The parsing if fine, but the List elements taken after this parsing I need to use them separately and I can't. I don't know how to iterate on that resulted, from the Parsing, List? For Example, how I can put them in a ListBuffer ...it may not make sense but let say I want that..because I am thinking that the shown List() taken from the parsing as a result is not a 'normal' List and I can't use the methods or constructs to manipulate on Lists

Comment: Yes, that is because `pval` is not a `List` at all, but a `ParseResult`. See the end of the answer where I use `getOrElse` to get the `List[String]` and store it in `ls`. You will be able to use `ls` inside a for loop.

Comment: opsss...amazing. It's perfect now. Thnx for sharing your great knowledge.